# I have a problem with combobox when showing scroll

Tags: excel, vba, scroll, combobox, alignment

I have a problem with combobox for showing content.
When I scroll some of the content, like in the attached picture, it is hidden.

[image]

My `combobox` text alignment is to the right

Comment: Maybe a very odd suggestion, but could you get away with a second, empty column, to act as a placeholder for the scrollbar?

Comment: how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from this [source](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/111948-problem-with-right-aligning-combo-boxes) you can put this code in your `UserForm.Initialize` procedure, e.g.:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim I As Long, TempString As String
UserForm1.ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2
TempString = LTrim$(Str$(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Width - 15))
UserForm1.ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = TempString & " pt; 15 pt"
For I = 1 To 10
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Hello" & Str$(I)
Next I

End Sub
```

[image]

Another option that works for me is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim I As Long
For I = 1 To 10
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Hello " & I & "     "
Next I

End Sub
```

This last option would just put enough trailing spaces to let the text appear fully. Note that when you use those values you will have to `TRIM` them down.